# Can't open .mdb links in Adobe Reader

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Today I tried to open a database link (.mdb) in a pdf file, and I received this error message:

[image]

This has never happened before, so I began my research. I found out it was a security feature added by Adobe that would disallow users from opening internet links, eliminating the risk of acquiring a virus through embedded hyperlinks.

The only way I found to turn this feature off was to edit the policy settings in the registry.

I went to - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown\cDefaultLaunchAttachmentPerms

I navigated to tBuiltInPermList and found the .mdb extension, changing the 3, to a 2.[image]

Changing the 3 to a 2 allows .mdb files to be opened in Reader after prompting the user to make sure they really want to open the file.

Is there another way around this that anyone else has found? I find it odd that Adobe would blame system admins for this issue, when its totally not.

Comment: Is this computer attached to a work (domain) network?

Comment: Yes, connected to a domain, but it's a lab I set up. Non-work related. Why?

Comment: @AnthonySims - Because this policy can be set by a active domain policy.  So it might be intential that its currently configured they way it was.  *The feature isn't exactly new though, and Adobe gets lots of heat for the exploits in PDF, and its mainly so that a javascript within a PDF can automatically download a file without user intervention.*  You an also disable Javascript but most people don't.